# Oracle APEX - Custom error messages for IG

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have an updatable IG that is updated with Automated row processing and when the user updates a row with the value that already exists in the database, an ugly unique constraint error message pops up. Any way I can customize error messages on IG while keeping Automated Row Processing? Or should I change the processing to PL/SQL?

Comment: Could you please share the exact error message?

Comment: `Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987: APEX - ORA-00001: unique constraint (MYSCHEMA.TABLE1_UK1) violated `

Answer (score 2):

There is an error handling function option in the application attributes section of Oracle Apex.

It is possible to add a function here and show user friendly errors for common error codes.

[image: appliication definition attributes]

[image: help section]

More detailed explaination can be found here - http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2018/06/automatically-capture-all-errors-and.html

Edit: 
Tested this on IG

[image: Tested on IG]

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but this is for capturing page errors not IG specifically

Comment: @CodingDuchess I tested this on IG and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

APEX provides a way to catch and handle such errors by providing an Error Handling Function. Navigate to the Shared Components > Application Definition Attributes and scroll down until you see the **Error Handling Function** attribute. There, you would put the name of a function that will handle errors.

If you check the doc, you'll see an example of this type of function: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/Example-of-an-Error-Handling-Function.html#GUID-2CD75881-1A59-4787-B04B-9AAEC14E1A82

The example function is highly commented to explain what types of things you can do. There's an example of how you can create a lookup table of friendly error messages and use the table to replace the cryptic ones (like your example) with something more clear.

Comment: I was juggling a few things when Anuswadh answered. :) I've not tested this with IG specifically, but I have no reason to believe that it wouldn't work.